# Parallel delete operations on S3 using PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have a situation where I need to delete a large number of files (hundreds of millions) from S3, and it takes, like, forever if you use the traditional approaches (even using python `boto3` package with `delete_objects`, to delete them in chunks of 1000, and processing it locally in 16 multiprocesses)

So, I developed an approach using PySpark, where I:

1. get the list of files I need to delete
2. parallelize it in a dataframe, partition it by prefix (considering that I have a limit of 3500 DELETE requests/sec per prefix)
3. get the underlying RDD and apply `delete_objects` using the `.mapPartitions()` method of the RDD
4. convert it to dataframe again (`.toDF()`)
5. run `.cache()` and `.count()` to force the execution of the requests

This is the function I am passing to `.mapPartitions()`:

```py
def delete_files(list_of_rows):

  for chunk in chunked_iterable(list_of_rows, 1000):

    session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='us-east-1')
    client = session.client('s3')

    files = list(chunk)
    bucket = files[0][0]

    delete = {'Objects': [{'Key': f[1]} for f in files]}

    response = client.delete_objects(
      Bucket=bucket,
      Delete=delete,
    )

    yield Row(
      deleted=len(response.get('Deleted'))
    )
```

It works nicely, except that depending on the number of files, I keep getting `SlowDown` (status code 503) exceptions, hitting the limits of 3500 DELETE requests/sec per prefix.

It does not make sense to me, considering that I am partitioning my rows by prefix [`.repartition("prefix")`] (meaning that I should not have the same prefix in more than one partition) and mapping the `delete_files` function to the partition at once.

In my head it is not possible that I am calling `delete_objects` for the same prefix at the same time, and so, I can not find a reason to keep hitting those limits.

Is there something else I should consider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you find any explanation about this?